# Is there a difference between initializing a sequence of parameters and a parameter array?

Tags: arrays, fortran

If I am going to calculate a polynomial by using nested parentheses, is there a difference between declaring each constant individually and declaring them as an array?

For example, is there a difference between

```
real(kind = c_double), parameter  :: &
            P0 =  .5,     &
            P1 =  .8,     &
            P2 = -.1,     &
            P3 = -.7,     &
            P4 = -.4,     &
            P5 = -.6, &
            P6 = -.2
```

and calculating

```
x = ((((((P6 * a + P5) * a + P4) * a + P3) * a + P2) * a + P1) * a + P0)
```

or

```
real(kind = c_double), parameter, dimension(7)  :: P = &
[.5, .8, -.1, -.7, -.4, -.6, -.2]
```

and calculating

```
x = ((((((P(7) * a + P(6)) * a + P(5)) * a + P(4)) * a + P(3)) * a + P(2)) * a + P(1))
```

Comment: Take care about the precision of constant values : you should write for instance .1d0 or .1_c_double instead of .1

Comment: @FrancoisJacq, thank you. I did in my actual code. This was shortened for the purpose of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there are differences, but these aren't differences that are important in your use here.

The differences come from the fact that given the (slightly different from the question) declarations

```
real, parameter :: P1=0.1, P2=0.2, P(2)=[0.1,0.2]
```

`P1` and `P2` are constants, but `P(1)` and `P(2)` aren't.  `P` is a constant, but that's not the same thing.  So, `P1` may be used in some circumstances where `P(1)` cannot.

However, in expressions like

```
((((((P6 * a + P5) * a + P4) * a + P3) * a + P2) * a + P1) * a + P0)
```

the constant nature is not important and elements of `P` may be used there just as easily.

Differences arise in cases such as complex literal constants and (for integers) kind parameters in literal constants.  Also, with `P(1)` being an array element it can be used in some ways unsuitable for `P1`.

---

I'll note a couple of things specific to the question:

- given `P0` is used, the array could be indexed from `0`:  `real, parameter, dimension(0:6) :: P=[...]`;
- one advantage of the array is that the number of elements may (in current Fortran, not F90) be implied:  `real, parameter, dimension(0:*) :: P=[...]`

Answer (score 1):

I want to point out that in the section on constant expressions, the standard says

> A constant expression is ...
>   (1) a constant or a subobject of a constant.

So where can `P1` be used where `P(1)` cannot? Certainly `P(1)` can be used where `P1` cannot, however.

The array method is really attractive in my opinion because it's so much easier to understand array expressions -- there could be some irregularity in the nested expression that the reader could miss, but not in the array formula:

```
program polyval
   use ISO_C_BINDING, only:C_DOUBLE
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: wp = C_DOUBLE
   real(wp), parameter :: P(0:*) = &
      [0.5_wp,0.8_wp,-0.1_wp,-0.7_wp,-0.4_wp,-0.6_wp,-0.2_wp]
   real(wp) a, x
   integer i
   a = 10
   x = sum([(a**i*P(i),i=0,ubound(P,1))])
   write(*,*) x
end program polyval
```

**EDIT**: I thought that by now Fortran compilers might be smart enough to recognize the above idiom for polynomial evaluation, but apparently I was wrong. I would have thought that

```
function poly1(x)
   use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, only: wp=> REAL64
   real(wp) x
   real(wp) poly1
   real(wp), parameter :: P0 = 0.5_wp, P1 = 0.8_wp, P2 = -0.1_wp, &
      P3 = -0.7_wp, P4 = -0.4_wp, P5 = -0.6_wp, P6 = -0.2_wp
   poly1 = (((((P6*x+P5)*x+P4)*x+P3)*x+P2)*x+P1)*x+P0
end function poly1
```

and

```
function poly2(x)
   use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, only: wp=> REAL64
   real(wp) x
   real(wp) poly2
   real(wp), parameter :: P(0:6) = &
      [0.5_wp,0.8_wp,-0.1_wp,-0.7_wp,-0.4_wp,-0.6_wp,-0.2_wp]
   integer i
   poly2 = sum([(x**i*P(i),i=0,ubound(P,1))])
end function poly2
```

would result in similar code, but both `gfortran -S -O3 -ffast-math -funroll-loops poly2.f90` and `ifort /Fa /c /fast /Qipo- poly2.f90` compute powers of `x` and an effective `DOT_PRODUCT` rather than using an efficient method. So maybe it is required to write out the expression longhand like assembly rather than a high-level language to get reasonable performance in this context.

**EDIT**: OK, so there seems to be one context where a REAL named constant can be used but a REAL constant expression cannot.

```
program test2
   use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, only:wp=>REAL64
   implicit none
   complex(wp) x
   real(wp), parameter :: P1 = 4*atan(1.0_wp)
   real(wp), parameter :: P(1) = exp(1.0_wp)
   x = (P1,0)
   write(*,*) x
!   x = (P(1),0) ! Fails because literal or named constant is required
   write(*,*) x
end program test2
```

But searching the standard I think that's the only case. Was it in f2003 that a named constant was first permitted in a *complex-literal-constant*? For completeness I offer an example where the constant expression can work but not the named constant:

```
module mymod
   use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV,only:wp=>REAL64
   implicit none
   contains
      subroutine sub(x)
         real(wp) x(*)
         write(*,*) x(1)
      end subroutine sub
end module mymod

program test3
   use mymod
   implicit none
   real(wp), parameter :: P1 = 4*atan(1.0_wp)
   real(wp), parameter :: P(1) = exp(1.0_wp)
!   call sub(P1)  ! Fails because array actual argument required
   call sub(P(1)) ! Succeeds due to sequence association
end program test3
```

Comment: I don't know whether you are actually asking about where `P1` can be used where `P(1)` cannot (it reads as a rhetorical question, but you don't seem to address it later), but `P1` is a constant whereas `P(1)` isn't.  Constants may be used in places where constant expressions may not (such as in `complex :: z=(P1,0)`).

Comment: Regarding using the nested parenthesis as opposed to the power operator, it's an implementation of [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) which is more efficient than using calls to exponentiation or power.

Comment: @francescalus I guess there is one context where a REAL named constant, not a constant expression, is required. I can't seem to find another, however. Of course there are more such contexts where an INTEGER named constant and not a constant expression is required, such as the *kind-param* in a literal. Had I thought about that I might have arrived at the COMPLEX literal case.

Comment: @Avraham My guess would have been that modern Fortran compilers could recognize the given idiom for evaluating a polynomial and optimized accordingly but I couldn't get ifort or gfortran to back me up on this. TT